# WHOIS for given TLD?

Tags: whois

How do I programatically determine the WHOIS server for a given TLD?

For name servers, I just query a.root-servers.net

Is there an equivalent procedure for WHOIS?

I know "host -t ns xxx." yields the DNS for a TLD: can the WHOIS 
server be derived from that result?

Comment: I think you can do this by following a chain of referrals from something like whois.iana.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the SRV-record _nicname._tcp.tld -

For example;

```
# dig +short SRV _nicname._tcp.no
0 0 43 whois.norid.no.
```

More information can be found in the [Wikipedia-article of whois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois#Server_advertisement_in_DNS).

That works for some tld's at least - but not .com.

tld.whois-servers.net is a commonly used alias that should point to a valid whois-server.  For example com.whois-servers.net

Comment: Thanks! It looks like "whois -h whois.iana.org xxx" does the trick perfectly, as does "host xxx.whois-servers.net" (as you note above). GNU prefers the latter, but the former seems more official to me. In either case, I got my answer! Updating jwhois also helped a lot!